# Why is Powershell adding blank spaces in string stored in a variable?

Tags: sql, string, powershell, char, space

I get a value from SQL db store it in a variable and concatenate it.
The length of the col. value is 1 in SQL but in PowerShell it shows as 3. Moreover `.Trim()` doesn't work.

`$rev.Length` is 3 when it should be 1
I have tried
`$revs= $revision.Trim()`
`$revs= $revision.Trim($null)`
`$revs= $revision.TrimStart()`
`$revs= $revision.End()`
`$revs= $revision -replace '\s',""`

Nones of these work.

Data type in SQL for this col. is char and collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Code:

```
   $revQuery = "SELECT  [MA_Rev] As Rev FROM [NML_Sidney].[dbo].[MADL_EngParts]  Where MAFN=$firstPartTrimmed AND MA_Rev IS NOT NULL"
   $revSql = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database $database -Query $revQuery
   $revision = $revSql.Rev 
   $revs= $revision.TrimEnd()
   $rev = "REV"+" "+$revs
   $rev.GetType().Name
   write-host $revs -ForegroundColor Red
   write-host $rev.length
```

Comment: What do you get from `$revision.where{ -not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_) }.Count` ?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I get 1

Comment: Well that's it, `$revSql.Rev` has some null values, so that should do it

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon  to the rescue, AGAIN!!! Thanks! But my original question stands, why is PowerShell doing this?  Secondly, why did `$revs= $revision.Trim($null)` not work

Comment: I don't think it's powershell doing this, I think `MA_Rev IS NOT NULL` is not enough, I feel `MA_Rev` has some only space / empty string values (which I don't think are considered the same as NULL in MSSQL)

Comment: `.Trim($null)` is not a valid syntax btw, `.Trim` can be used with a string or array of strings but it doesnt filter null values from an array